# JavaScript Postback on condition

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I need help with the javascript below please. I have 2 text boxes and 1 button on my form. What I would like to happen is if User enters a value in textbox one and not textbox two, then event need not be fired. However, if there is a value in textbox one and then textbox 2 then I want a post back to fire. My code below does not seem to be doing this at all and I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix this or better still figure it out. Thanks in advance

```
function Changed(textControl) {
    //  alert(textControl.value);
    var conlength = document.getElementById('<%=txtLength.ClientID %>');
    var conwidth = document.getElementById('<%=txtwidth.ClientID %>');
    if (conlength != null && conwidth != null) {
        if (conlength.value != null && conlength.value != ' ' && conwidth.value != null && conwidth.value != ' ') {
            // ' ' corresponds to c#'s String.Empty                
            __doPostBack(document.getElementById('<%=btncalcboardfeet.ClientID %>'), 'Calculate Board Feet Button event has been fired');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of that last if statement just try the following:

```
if (conlength.value && conwidth.value) {
            // ' ' corresponds to c#'s String.Empty                
            __doPostBack(document.getElementById('<%=btncalcboardfeet.ClientID %>'), 'Calculate Board Feet Button event has been fired');
}
```

Comment: Wait, just another thing! When I initially launch my page and enter values in textbox 1 and then textbox 2, the click event is fired but the textboxes are instead cleared of their values and so  nothing else happens as a result. Is there something I need to do in addition to get this working normal?

Comment: That doesn't seem related to this code. Nothing here modifies any values. Is there something else running on the page?

Comment: Well.... for the one the controls are contained in a Usercontrol which is dynamically loaded on the page and reloaded on postbacks. Could that be an issue and if yes, is there a way I can take care of that? I mean when I had an actual button on the page that the user would have to click to initiate postback, I did not have this problem. Now I have Javascript doing the button clicking for me and this problem shows up. Is there supposed to be some difference?

Comment: If it worked with a normal form submit before, you could just fire the `submit()` function on the parent form, rather than call the postback yourself. I'm not incredibly familiar with .NET so I can't help in that regard. Sounds like a different issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the length of the VALUE, not the element itself:

```
var conlength = document.getElementById('<%=txtLength.ClientID %>').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a simpler approach ... if your condition is met, programmatically click your submit button ;-)  it's super simple using something like jquery even if you're into that sort of thing:

```
$("#<%=btncalcboardfeet.ClientID %>").click();
```

That way you don't have to try to figure out what internal javascript function asp.net is trying to call (as that may change in the future (however unlikely)).

*edit:* non jQuery version:

```
document.getElementById("<%=btncalcboardfeet.ClientID %>").click();
```

Comment: THat would work IF I could use jquery in my code but I am not to do that .

Comment: see edit, non jquery version is just as easy (albeit a few characters longer) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms and are using the asp:TextBox to collect the information, you can use the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp) to ensure that both fields have a value before the page will postback.